# Git pushing a branch to remote not working

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I created a local branch by using

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

Then I made certain changes to it and pushed to remote with

```
git push origin mybranch
```

However, I cannot see my local changes in the remote `mybranch`.
Therefore, I tried to push again:

```
git push origin mybranch:mybranch
```

Now I get message that everything is up-to-date, but I can see that there are changes in the local branch. Running `git branch` shows `mybranch` as the local selected branch. I have done this operation in the past, but somehow, not able to recollect how I did that.

Can someone please help?

Comment: if I run git diff, I see the changes made.

Comment: if it helps, when I go to github.com, I see message that this branch (mybranch) is 22 commits behind the master. I have tried deleting remote branch and pushing again. But still not working.

Comment: I think I am typing too many self comments, but looks like because I did not create my local branch out of latest master, I am getting issues. I am going to try to get latest master and then do this operation again.

Comment: @Sumod If you are able to see the changes done in "git diff" means you might have not run "git add" and "git commit". If not, just have a try once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you write that, after you created `mybranch`, you

> made certain changes to it and pushed to remote.

But did you actually stage your changes and create a commit before attempting to push? It seems that you didn't because, in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532504/git-pushing-a-branch-to-remote-not-working#comment39862987_25532504) of your comments, you also write

> if I run `git diff`, I see the changes made.

The `git diff` command shows the differences between your working tree and the staging area. The fact that `git diff` outputs something (instead of nothing) can mean only one thing: you have a *dirty working tree*. In other words, there are discrepancies between your working tree and the staging area.

You won't be able to push those changes to remote until you stage them, with

```
git add <paths>
```

and create a commit, for instance with

```
git commit -m "descriptive message"
```

Then, you should be able to push your branch (whose tip will be that new commit) to remote `origin`:

```
git push origin mybranch
```